# Studying the evolution of laplacian in NS equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, linear-pde, numerical-analysis-of-pde

The Navier-Stokes equation in $\mathbb{R}^3$ subjected to no gravitational forces are provided by:

\begin{equation}\label{Eq1}
 \dfrac{\partial }{\partial t} \textbf{u} + \left(\textbf{u}\cdot \nabla \right)\textbf{u} =    \nu \bigtriangleup \textbf{u}-\dfrac{1}{\rho}  \nabla p 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{Eq2}
\nabla \cdot \textbf{u} = 0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{Eq3}
\textbf{u}(x,0) = \textbf{u}^0(x).
\end{equation}

Here $\rho>0$ is a scalar which represents the fluids density and $\nu>0$ is a scalar which denotes the fluids kinetic viscosity.

I want to study the evolution of the Laplacian of the velocity. If it is a positive quantity, will it remain positive over time? Generally, if a function is smooth the Laplacian is smooth. Is there anything we can say about the overall sign of the diffusion of the velocity. Can the sign be periodic in nature. If the Laplacian is negative, will it remain negative over time.

I thought about computing the Laplacian of both sides of the first equation but that only leads to a double Laplacian and multiple non-linear terms. The sign seems to depend on the sign of the pressure and the sign of the derivative.

Another idea was to take the time derivative as the pressure only depends on space then it will vanish. But this will give us the derivative of the Laplacian.